# Alternar valores en bucle y limitar repeticiones/cambios

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy usando dataframes de PANDAS y quiero crear un horario con la siguiente información

```
p_in = ['8:00','16:00']
p_out = ['15:00','23:00']
l_in = ['11:00','18:00']
l_out = ['11:30','18:30']
names = {'Nombres':['nom1','nom2','nom3','nom4','nom5']}
df_names = pd.DataFrame(names)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(5):
    name = df_names.loc[i,'Nombres']
    user_type = 'A'
    punch_in = random.choice(p_in)
    if punch_in == p_in[0]:
        punch_out = p_out[0]
        lunch_in = l_in[0]
        lunch_out = l_out[0]
    else:
        punch_out = p_out[1]
        lunch_in = l_in[1]
        lunch_out = l_out[1]
    linedict = {'Name':[name],
                'Type':[user_type],
                'Punch In':[punch_in],
                'Punch Out':[punch_out],
                'Lunch In':[lunch_in],
                'Lunch Out':[lunch_out]}
    line = pd.DataFrame(linedict)
    df = pd.concat([df, line])

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Con base a los nombres, necesito que haga lo siguiente:

Alternar entre dos horarios 8 y 15, es decir fila 0 =8, fila 1 =15, fila 2 =8, etc...

Lo horarios con desfase de 30 min y limitados de 11 a 14, por ejemplo fila0=11:00, fila1=11:30... fila6=14:00, fila7=11:00

Mi intención es que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
   Name Type Punch In Punch Out Lunch In Lunch Out
0  nom1    A     8:00     15:00    12:00     12:30
1  nom3    A     8:00     15:00    12:30     13:00
2  nom5    A     8:00     15:00    13:00     13:30
3  nom2    A    16:00     23:00    19:00     19:30
4  nom4    A    16:00     23:00    19:30     20:00
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto de manera más limpia?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es importante mantener una sola pregunta por publicación para que otros usuarios puedan encontrar la información que necesitan fácilmente. Voy a agregar la respuesta de ¿Cómo alternar valores en un `dataframe`? Pero la parte de desfasar el horario es mejor que crees una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `list comprehension` y `np.arange()` para crear una nueva lista de valores alternados

Primero generamos un arreglo del rango que necesitas, en tu caso sería 5

```
np.arange(5)
```

Resultado

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Si sacamos el módulo de 2 de ese arreglo entonces tendríamos un arreglo que alterna entre 0 y 1

```
np.arange(5)%2
```

Resultado (Si deseas cambiar el tipo de dato lo puedes hacer, para el ejemplo voy a dejar `int32`)

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Haciendo un `list comprehension` utilizando `p_in` y el arreglo anterior obtenemos lo siguiente

```
[p_in[x] for x in (np.arange(5)%2)]
```

Resultado

```
['8:00', '16:00', '8:00', '16:00', '8:00']
```

Y podemos utilizar este nuevo arreglo para la columna del `dataframe`

```
df['Punch In'] = [p_in[x] for x in (np.arange(5)%2)]
```

Ahora, para hacerlo dinámico, podemos asignar la longitud de los índices del `dataframe` a una variable y esa variable utilizarla en el `np.arange()`. También podemos crear todas las columnas al mismo tiempo y nos queda muy compacto

```
l = len(df.index)
df['Punch In'], df['Punch Out'], df['Lunch In'], df['Lunch Out'] = [p_in[x] for x in (np.arange(l)%2)], [p_out[x] for x in (np.arange(l)%2)], [l_in[x] for x in (np.arange(l)%2)], [l_out[x] for x in (np.arange(l)%2)]
```

Resultado

```
    Nombres Punch In    Punch Out   Lunch In    Lunch Out
0   nom1    8:00        15:00       11:00       11:30
1   nom2    16:00       23:00       18:00       18:30
2   nom3    8:00        15:00       11:00       11:30
3   nom4    16:00       23:00       18:00       18:30
4   nom5    8:00        15:00       11:00       11:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo recomendaría crear una lista con todos los datos, luego hacer un ciclo y finalmente crear el dataframe, ya que estar creando un dataframe en cada ciclo no es nada eficiente.

Para saber el número de veces que iteraremos lo haremos mediante una lista. La lista de nombres nos viene bien en este caso, ya que contiene los nombres y el número de filas. Para guardar los datos utilizaré una lista normal.

Para el desplazo de horarios utilizaré el módulo `datetime` y sus funciones `datetime` y `timedelta` que nos permitirá hacer operaciones con las horas.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

p_in = ['8:00','16:00']
p_out = ['15:00','23:00']
l_in = ['11:00','18:00']

data = []
flag, n = False, 0
for name in ['nom1','nom2','nom3','nom4','nom5']:
    i = not not flag
    
    start_time = l_in[1] if flag else l_in[0]
    launch_in = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M")+timedelta(minutes=30*n)
    launch_out = launch_in+timedelta(minutes=30)

    data.append([name, "A", p_in[i], p_out[i], launch_in, launch_out])

    n+= 1 if flag else 0
    flag=not flag

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Lo que hace este código es iterar sobre los nombres y elegir el `p_in` y `p_out` de acuerdo a un `flag` que nos indicará si es verdadero o falso. En caso ser verdadero se utiliza la segunda posición y en caso de ser falso la primera, para eso nos ayudamos de un pequeño truquito de los números `1` y `0` si hacemos `int(True)` devolverá `1` y para `False` devolverá `0`, este resultado será el mismo si hacemos `not not True` al hacer una doble negación no cambia el valor pero ahora python devolverá un número.

Este *flag* también nos ayudará a saber desde que hora empezamos, si `flag` es `True` empezaremos desde la hora `18:00` y si es `False` desde `11:00` (ojo el código incluye esas horas y empiezan desde esas). Luego solo utilizamos `datetime.strptime` para convertir el string a una fecha de tipo `datetime` con la que podemos operar.

Adicionalmente hay una variable `n` cuyo valor incrementará si `flag` es verdadero y se mantendrá si no lo es, esto nos sirve para tener el control de cuanto hay que incrementar la hora inicial.

Con `timedelta(minutes=30*n)` estamos añadiendo `30*n` minutos. Luego de todo ese proceso generamos el dataframe y listo!

Una cosa es que las fechas aparecerán con todos los datos, es decir con año, mes, día, hora, minuto, segundo. Si solo queremos la hora y el minuto entonces debemos acceder a dichos atributos. Para ello deberías crear unas variables más.

```py
launch_in, launch_out = f"{launch_in.hour}:{launch_in.minute}", f"{launch_out.hour}:{launch_out.minute}"
```

Esto lo agregarías antes de crear el DataFrame.